# What is causing this forfiles error?

Tags: batch-file

I'm running this in batch file:

`forfiles /p "%~dp0" /c "echo @FILE"`

and when I run it, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\New folder>forfiles /p "C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\New folder\" /c "echo @FILE"
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@FILE'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.
```

What's the problem with `@FILE`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%~dp0` includes a tailing backslash. And this is what is causing your problems (this and what monacraft points)

So, change your code to

```
forfiles /p "%~dp0." /c "cmd /c echo @FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

Use `cmd /c`

```
forfiles /p "%~dp0" /c "cmd /c echo @FILE"
```

And why use `@echo file` in the first place?

```
forfiles /p "%~dp0"
```

Both should work.

Mona